# 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' error when trying to compare column in dataframe with single data point

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe z, of which one of the columns are in datetime format:

```
index       time
0      2017-03-01 09:30:00.233
1      2017-03-01 09:30:00.243
2      2017-03-01 09:30:00.319
3      2017-03-01 09:30:00.981
4      2017-03-01 09:30:02.555
5      2017-03-01 09:30:02.959
6      2017-03-01 09:30:03.908
7      2017-03-01 09:30:12.659
8      2017-03-01 09:30:19.006
9      2017-03-01 09:30:22.990
10     2017-03-01 09:30:23.166
11     2017-03-01 09:30:27.879
12     2017-03-01 09:30:28.370
```

Basically, I want to delete the rows that is before a specific time in the data. For example, let's say in this case I want to delete all rows before 09:30:22.990 (row 9). What I have is:

```
first_trade_AM = z['Time'][z['Time'].dt.day == date][z['EventType'] == 'trade'].head(1)  

for simplicity's sake, lets say this formula returns 
    9      2017-03-01 09:30:22.990

then I have 

z.drop(z['Time'][z['Time'].dt.day == date] < first_trade_AM)
```

but I get the error message:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Been stuck here for a while. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The dataset I posted above is a subset of the entire month's worth of data. Every single day has a unique first_trade_AM, which I found using:

```
for date in z['Time'].dt.day.unique():
    first_trade_AM = z.loc[(z['Time'].dt.day == date) & (z['EventType'] == 'trade'), 'Time'].head(1).item()
```

My follow-up question being, how do I delete all the observations for unique days BEFORE the particular day's unique first_trade_AM, without affecting the data from other dates?

EDIT:

More general data:

```
index  time                      EventType
0      2017-03-01 09:30:00.233       other
1      2017-03-01 09:30:00.243       trade
2      2017-03-01 09:30:00.319       trade       
3      2017-03-01 09:30:00.981       other
4      2017-03-01 09:30:02.555       other
5      2017-03-02 09:30:02.959       other 
6      2017-03-02 09:30:03.908       other   
7      2017-03-02 09:30:12.659       trade 
8      2017-03-02 09:30:19.006       trade
9      2017-03-02 09:30:22.990       trade
10     2017-03-02 09:30:23.166       other
11     2017-03-02 09:30:27.879       other 
12     2017-03-02 09:30:28.370       other
```

Comment: I add more general data, canyou add desired ouptut? Also if necessary modify it, but please get minimal 2 different days like `2017-03-01` and `2017-03-02`

Comment: Yes, so in the edited data above, i want to delete rows with index 0,5,6. Basically remove all observations before the first "EventType = trade" for each day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best is for `datetime`s select by position, here by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
first_obs_AM = z.loc[(z['Time'].dt.day == date) & (z['EventType'] == 'trade'), 'Time'].iat[0]
```

---

And last filter out values less as `first_trade_AM`, so need change `<` to `>=`:

```
z = z[z['Time'] >= first_trade_AM]
```

same as solution with invert mask by `~`:

```
z = z[~(z['Time'] < first_trade_AM)]
```

---

If want compare dates:

```
z = z[z['Time'].dt.date >= first_trade_AM.date()]
```

EDIT:

You can compare `0` created by [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) and filter out by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = (z['EventType'] == 'trade').groupby(z['time'].dt.day).cumsum() != 0

z = z[m]
print (z)
                         time EventType
index                                  
1     2017-03-01 09:30:00.243     trade
2     2017-03-01 09:30:00.319     trade
3     2017-03-01 09:30:00.981     other
4     2017-03-01 09:30:02.555     other
7     2017-03-02 09:30:12.659     trade
8     2017-03-02 09:30:19.006     trade
9     2017-03-02 09:30:22.990     trade
10    2017-03-02 09:30:23.166     other
11    2017-03-02 09:30:27.879     other
12    2017-03-02 09:30:28.370     other
```

Detail:

```
print ((z['EventType'] == 'trade').groupby(z['time'].dt.day).cumsum())
index
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     1.0
8     2.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    3.0
Name: EventType, dtype: float64

print ((z['EventType'] == 'trade').groupby(z['time'].dt.day).cumsum() != 0)
index
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
Name: EventType, dtype: bool
```

Comment: so if I'm clear, the .item() function turns the datetime into a scalar right? Then when I try to compare using z.drop(z['Time'][z['Time'].dt.day == date] < first_trade_AM) I am comparing a datetime column vs a scalar. In this case, I get the error TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: Thanks! Please check out my follow up question if you are willing.

Comment: Can you change input data by this edit and add desired output? Thanks.

Comment: I still have the same error trying to compare a datetime with a scalar

Comment: Hmm, what error? Do you campare `date` with `dates` and `datetime`s with `datetime`?

Comment: because is impossible compare `date`s with datetimes like `z[z['Time'].dt.date >= first_trade_AM]` - `first_trade_AM` is datetime

Comment: And I notice your edit, `.head(1).item()` is same as `.iat[0]`

Comment: I changed my filter to z = z[z['Time'] >= first_trade_AM] like you suggested

Comment: oops, I test is and `.iat[0]` is necessary, because sometimes `.item()` convert datetimes bad. Sorry. I remove it from answer.

Comment: awesome. it's working now. any suggestions on how to do the loop over different dates?

Comment: It seems loop here is not necessary. Can I change your input data and do you add desired ouptut?